# SQL Code to use not exists in

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Per_all_people_f

```
name  person_id  emp_flag  effective_start_date   effective_end_date   DOJ
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
ABC   123          Y       30-MAR-2011              30-MAR-2013       10-FEB-2011
ABC   123          Y       24-FEB-2011              27-FEB-2011       10-FEB-2011
DEF   345          N       10-APR-2012              30-DEC-4712       15-SEP-2011
```

per_chcklist

```
 person_id   name
  ------------------   
123         C1
456         C2 
345         C3
```

ACTUAL_TERMINATION_DATE

```
person_id   TERM_DATE
      ------------------   
    123         30-SEP-2013
    456         30-AUG-2013
    345         29-AUG-2013
```

now i want to calculate all the all those person ids which are in Per_all_people_f and whose TERM_DATE is there in ACTUAL_TERMINATION_DATE but is not in per_chcklist.

i want to use simple not exists in the query. Query i have written is :-

```
select papf.person_id,
papf.name
from per_all_people_f papf,
per_chcklist pc,
ACTUAL_TERMINATION_DATE atd

where papf.person_id=atd.person_id
and atd.TERM_DATE is not null
and pc.person_is!=papf.person_id;
```

but this is not giving me the answer.

Comment: You should replace implicit joins with standard explicit joins.  Ie: `FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.ID = b.ID JOIN table3 c ON a.ID = c.ID`  etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might suggest that you write this query using `exists` and `not exists`.  It more closely matches your requirements:

```
select papf.person_id, papf.name
from per_all_people_f papf
where exists (select 1
              from ACTUAL_TERMINATION_DATE atd
              where atd.TERM_DATE = papf.TERM_DATE and atd.person_id = papf.person_id
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from per_chcklist pc
                  where papf.person_id = pc.person_id
                 );
```

After you have this work, you can figure out how to express this as explicit joins, if you want to learn more about joins.